# Laravel- How to use switch case in javascript if I passed the variable to controller and saved in database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I working in laravel and I send many data include dropdown list which have value, 0,1,2 which means Top,Right,Left the problem is when Im using the update function in controller only I get 0 or 1 or 2 depends on what I entered and have to refresh to see the text bcause Im using json and ajax after click save.

**Html**

```
<select class="form-control" id="position_edit" name="position_edit">
                <option value="0">TOP</option>
                <option value="1">RIGHT</option>
                 <option value="2">LEFT</option>
                <option value="3">BOTTOM</option>
               </select>
```

**controller**

```
public function updatebanner(Request $request)
{
    if ($request->hasFile('image')) {
    $imagename = time().'.'.$request->file('image')->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $path =$request->file('image')->storeAs('/images', $imagename);

    $post = Advertisement::findOrFail($request->id);
    $post->adver_title =  $request->title_edit; 
    $post->adver_url =  $request->url_edit; 
    $post->adver_position =  $request->position_edit; 
    $post->adver_photo = $imagename; 
    $post->save();
}
```

**code in ajax**

```
$('.item' + data.id).replaceWith("
<tr class='item" + data.id + "'>
   <td  class='col1'>" + data.id + "</td>
   <td><img src='images/" + data.adver_photo + "'style='width: 50%;margin-left: 35px;border-radius: 3px;border: 1px solid #1a2732;' /> </td>
   <td>" + data.adver_title + "</td>
   <td>" +data.adver_position+ "</td>
   </td>
   <td class='text-center'><input type='checkbox' class='edit_published' data-id='" + data.id + " '></td>
   <td style='text-align:center;'>Right Now!</td>
   <td><button class='show-modal btn btn-success' data-id='" + data.id + "' data-titlefield='" + data.adver_title + "' data-photofield='images/" + data.adver_photo + "'><span class='fa fa-eye'></span> Show</button> <button class='edit-modal btn btn-info' data-id='" + data.id + "' data-titlefield='" + data.adver_title + "' data-photofield='images/" + data.adver_photo + "'><span class='fa fa-pencil-square'></span> Edit</button> <button class='delete-modal btn btn-danger' data-id='" + data.id + "' data-titlefield='" + data.adver_title + "' data-photofield='images/" + data.adver_photo + "'><span class='fa fa-trash-o'></span> Delete</button></td>
</tr>
");
```

I tried to use the **next code** but the problem doesn't work if adver_position value saved on database, it will return blank without any number or text and have to refresh page to see the text

```
   var content = "<tr class='item" + data.id + "'> "
            +  "<td  class='col1'>" + data.id + "</td> "
            +  "<td><img src='images/" + data.adver_photo + "'style='width: 50%;margin-left: 35px;border-radius: 3px;border: 1px solid #1a2732;' /> </td>" 
            +  "<td>" + data.adver_title + "</td>"
            +  "<td> ";

    switch(data.adver_position) {
case 0:
    content = content + "TOP";
    break;
case 1:
    content = content + "RIGHT";
    break;
case 2:
    content = content + "LEFT";
    break;
case 3:
    content = content + "BOTTOM";
    break;
}

content = content + "</td> </tr>"


 $('.item' + data.id).replaceWith(content);
```

Comment: Can you add your controller code ?

Comment: Added controller, hope find help

Comment: Ok why don't you use enum for the field `adver_position` and in the select use directly `<option value="RIGHT">RIGHT</option>` ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try:

```
content += $('#position_edit option:checked').text();
```

Instead of the `switch`. This will simply assign the text of the selected position.

**Edit:** Replace All this:

```
    switch(data.adver_position) {
case 0:
    content = content + "TOP";
    break;
case 1:
    content = content + "RIGHT";
    break;
case 2:
    content = content + "LEFT";
    break;
case 3:
    content = content + "BOTTOM";
    break;
}
```

With the provided solution.

Comment: how Can I replace this? I tried but javascript stopped working

Comment: great, many thaaaaaaaaaaanks just want to add style='text-align:center;' sorry im beginner

Comment: to the result of content += $('#position_edit option:checked').text();

Comment: @GhadahSalman than try this `+  "<td style='text-align:center;'> ";` in the line after `+  "<td>" + data.adver_title + "</td>"`

Answer (score 2):

From my understanding of your question, I think when you save in to database from your controller, you don't return response to frontend, that can be used to update your content.

Why not do something like this?

```
public function updatebanner(Request $request)
  {
 if ($request->hasFile('image')) {
 $imagename = time().'.'.$request->file('image')->getClientOriginalExtension();
$path =$request->file('image')->storeAs('/images', $imagename);

$post = Advertisement::findOrFail($request->id);
$post->adver_title =  $request->title_edit; 
$post->adver_url =  $request->url_edit; 
$post->adver_position =  $request->position_edit; 
 $post->adver_photo = $imagename; 
 $post->save();
return response(['item'=>$post]); /// return response

}
```